# Filtering data in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables `account_agent` and `bulk_index`. The data on each table is as follows

`account_agent`

```
id         name         
1          Tom           
2          Brad           
3          John           
4          Jan        
5          Bartosz
```

`account_agent to filter`

```
id         name         
1          Tom              
3          John              
5          Bartosz
```

using these tables I want to make a normalized view that contains all agents from first table, but without agents placed in second table.

`account_agent_filtered`

```
name         code         
2            Brad 
4            Jan
```

I have a lot of data and with cross join I could just do an opposite thing, but now I do not want to match. I want to filter and I do not have any idea how to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i think it is downvoted because the simplest way to find the solution is to read about LEFT JOIN even something... LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL is described in any documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have an `except` set operator, but you could emulate this behavior using `exists`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   account_agent aa
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   account_agent_to_filter aatf
                   WHERE  aa.id = aatf.id AND aa.name = aatf.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024616/10138734):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM account_agent t1
LEFT JOIN account_agent_to_filter t2 USING (id, name)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```